# How to disable rating stars from product carousel

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2 porto theme where it has a product carousel and it shows rating stars. I need to disable it from the product carousel.

Can it possible to disable?? Please help...

Comment: Are you using magento 2 or magento 1.9 ?

Comment: I am using magento2

Comment: I update my answer below check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom theme will be having a specific module for displaying the carousel, So for theme specific change you got to navigate to that module and comment down the rating block code.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope this is use full for you

if you want remove rating in Product details page

go to you custom theme path

```
 app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

add below line

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
```

Next,

if you want remove rating in category page

go to you custom theme path

```
    app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

add below line

```
   <referenceContainer name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
```

remove var/* then check it.

Comment: Thank u all both ways r I have tried working fine...

Comment: Could you please tell how to add the rating stars in my custom product slider which i have in home page